# What is the technical term for multiplying two matrices same as their indexes and summing it all together

Tags: matrices

For example,

$$
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
    a & b \\
    c & d \\
  \end{array} } \right]
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
    a_{1} & b_{1} \\
    c_{1} & d_{1} \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$$

the "multiplication" of the above 2 matrices would give me

$$
a\times a_1 + b\times b_1 + c\times c_1 + d\times d_1 
$$

as a number, not a matrix. What would the technical term be?

Comment: It is $trace(M^T N)$ where $M$ is your first matrix and $N$ the second. This is their inner product.

Comment: It's called the Frobenius or Hilbert-Schmidt inner product: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input here is two vectors from $M_n(\mathbb{F})$ and output is a number i.e. a scalar. So *it may* qualify as an inner product on matrices. You just need to check whether it satisfies the three properties for it.

Indeed this does satisfy, and is called the [Frobenius inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20Frobenius%20inner%20product%20is%20a,are%20not%20restricted%20to%20be%20square%20matrices%20.).

Comment: Thanks. Just to check, what are the three properties? I know at least 1 of them is that matrix A and matrix B has to be of same dimensions.

Comment: The properties for inner product I mean. This inner product being sum of component wise multiplication, is similar to usual dot product in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$. I hope you figured out the properties now.